# How to remove Crosswalk without losing app data?

Tags: android, cordova, chromium, indexeddb, crosswalk

I'd like to remove Crosswalk 23 from my Cordova project. My problem is, that I'm storing data in an IndexedDB for offline work and I don't want to our customers to re-sync all the data after updating the app. Is there a safe way to transfer the data to the native Android webview during the first start after updating to the new version?

Best regards
Sven

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove Crosswalk from an existing app but need to preserve the user's data (Local Storage, IndexedDB, WebSQL), you can use [cordova-plugin-crosswalk-data-migration](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-data-migration) to migrate the data from Crosswalk back to the system webview in a subsequent app update in which Crosswalk has been removed:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-crosswalk-data-migration
```